# Etherpad and Wordpress, possible?

Tags: wordpress, etherpad

I recently stumbled upon Etherpad, it's a collaborative writing tool 
http://code.google.com/p/etherpad/ - main project page

online Examples:
http://piratepad.net/ 
http://ietherpad.com/ 
http://typewith.me/

I want to add this engine somehow to my wordpress and let people collaborate their posts, 
I'm wondering if it has been done before and/or does it take more than 
shared hosting (that is what I have) to do it [server capabilities or what-not] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I think this is a complicated way to go about it. Also, Etherpad allows some very basic font formatting but no images and such things you might want to include in a blog. Instead I suggest looking for some Wordpress plugin for collaborative writing, and you might find something less "real-timey" but perhaps good enough.

Or if you really want to try with Etherpad:
Etherpad needs lots of memory (RAM) to run. A typical configuration is 1 GB, but it might be possible to get by on 128MB dedicated to Etherpad. This means you'll need at least 256MB in total for a first attempt. Your shared host also needs to have a Java server installed (typically Jetty) and some proxying server (typically nginx). All in all, you have some work ahead of you in just getting Etherpad up and running. After that, integrating into the Wordpress blog editor. If/how this can be done, I don't know. I'd probably do a client-side javascript-hack to get the Wordpress textarea or richtext editarea to update from the Etherpad readonly view, which is the only place where you can get the contents of a pad as more-or-less raw source text.

Comment: Haven't found a collaborative Wordpress plugin, the closest thing was Google Wave Element but due to the fact that Wave is dead...

Comment: Wave is announced that it will be shut off... sometime. This might give you enough time to use mentioned WP plugin to evaluate your needs. Otherwise, that plugin might have a forum where you can get help from others in your same situation. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution would be to just add an Etherpad page through an iFrame. See this post for example - http://www.knowledgepolicy.com/2010/02/embed-etherpad-into-blogpost-or-on-any.html

Answer (score 0):

In theory it's possible to replace Wordpress' editor with an Etherpad Lite iFrame.  Etherpad now allows image/font editing and table support as plugins.

Java is no longer required for Etherpad, NodeJS however is.

[Here is a plugin that is in development that does what you want](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-etherpad-lite/) - however development seemed to stop in early 2012.

Answer (score 0):

http://participad.org/ seems to be the best solution in this space to date.  I haven't tested it on my own site, but they have an at least partially-working demo online.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It is possible. WordPress now has a [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/participad/). The plugin has three modules which enables an Editor in dashboard and let you edit via front-end.

You can find more details on their [FAQ](http://participad.org/faqs/) page.